# PyTorch - BCELoss: ValueError: Target and input must have the same number of elements

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch, mnist, torchvision

When I use `BCELoss` as the loss function of my neural network, getting the `ValueError: Target and input must have the same number of elements`.

Here is my code for test phase (which is a quite typical test phase code):

```
network.eval()
test_loss = 0
correct = 0
with torch.no_grad():
    for data, target in test_loader:
        data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)

    output = network(data)
    output = output.to(device)
    test_loss += loss_function(output, target).item() # error happens here
    _, predicted = torch.max(output.data, 1)
    correct += (predicted == target).sum().item()
```

The shape of the variable `output` is `[1000, 10]` as there are `10` target classes (in *MNIST* dataset), and the shape of the variable `target` is `[1000]` as it contains the target classes of the tested batch (the batch size for test is set to `10`). So, the question is how can I apply `BCELoss` as the loss function of a `CNN` network?

p.s. The dataset I use is the *MNIST* dataset which is provided by the `torchvision` library.

p.s. [The answer provided to a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47680685/282855) does not propose a solution for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47680685/282855) you claim does not propose a solution, does in fact solves your problem:

> your targets are incomplete! If there are multiple classes, you should work with [`torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#crossentropyloss) instead of [`torch.nn.BCELoss()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#bceloss)

To recap, `torch.nn.BCELoss()` is intended to be used for a task of classifying `c` *independant* binary attributes per input example. You, on the other hand, have the task of classifying each output into *one of `c` mutually exclusive* classes. For this task you need a different loss, `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`.
The different tasks, represented by the different loss functions call for different supervision (labels). If you want to classify each example to one of `c` mutually exclusive classes, you only need one integer label for each example (as you have in your mnist example). However, if you want to classify each example into `c` independent binary attributes, you need, for each example `c` binary labels - and this is why pytorch gives you an error.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So, what are the other loss functions that can be used for my case as I am looking for the comparison of their performances?